# Unable to maintain a constant bitrate FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I am new to StackOverflow. And I don't know how to structure the question properly.

I am trying to create media streaming server for my project where a raspberry camera will stream to nginx rtmp server and my computer will periodically make chunks out of the streams and saves them as `.h264`.

This is my ffmpeg command running on `picamera` (I am using python 2.7 and picamera library).

```
cmdline = ['ffmpeg', '-i','-','-vcodec','copy','-crf','30','-maxrate','2M','-bufsize',' 1M','-an', '-f','flv', Cam_URL]
logger.debug("Starting the streaming process to server")
rtmpstream = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
try:
    camera.framerate = 24
    camera.resolution = (1280, 720)
    camera.brightness = int(config_hash['Brightness'])
    camera.rotation = int(config_hash['Rotation'])
    camera.iso = int(config_hash['ISO'])
    camera.sharpness = int(config_hash['Sharpness'])
    camera.start_recording(rtmpstream.stdin, quality = 20,bitrate = 0, format = 'h264')
```

`ffmpeg` on my machine:

```
ffmpeg -i (media server url) -vcodec copy -maxrate 2M -bufsize 1M qwertyuip.h264
```

The bitrate on pi stays constant at around 2Mbits bitrate before recording, but when I start to record on my PC, the bit rate on the pi increases like crazy to 11000kbits. This is using up all my bandwidth.

Can you please help me maintaining a nearly constant bitrate?

Answer (score 1):

The options `-vcodec copy` and `-maxrate 2M` are mutually exclusive: If the stream is copied (a.o.t. reencoded), ffmpeg has no influence over the data rate (apart from padding) - so the data rate as output by your camera will be the data rate ffmpeg puts through.

You have two options:

- Reencode the video (along the lines of `-c:v h264 -b:v 2M`), but I am doubtfull that the RasPi has enough muscle to do so while running the camera server as well
- Have your camera server produce a sane output rate. This is the way I would approach the problem, first of all taking a look at what output options and settings it allows.

Comment: Thanks, @eugen. The second option has really helped me